# How can I populate Treeview with Mega Link folder in C#?

Tags: treeview, mega-api

I'm trying to populate a Treeview with my own link from Mega link. I'm using Megaapiclient. I have access to files and folders, but I have no idea how to populate with full path. I can create Nodes for both files and folders but not together.

My code:

```
        private void directoryPath(string URL, string name)
        {
            var client = new MegaApiClient();
            client.Login(Form3.User, Form3.Pass);

            Uri fileLink = new Uri(URL);

            IEnumerable<INode> nodes = client.GetNodesFromLink(fileLink);

            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name);
            var directories = nodes.Where(x => x.Type == NodeType.Directory);
            var files = nodes.Where(x => x.Type == NodeType.File);

            foreach (var dir in directories)
            {
                mainWindow.treeView1.Nodes.Add(dir.Name);
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                mainWindow.treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
            }

            mainWindow.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            this.Dispose();
        }
```

Can someone please help me?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library and treeview control you're using, but from the code it looks like you're creating directory nodes and file nodes independently - why not a nested loop, where you are adding file nodes per each directory node (also, to that node, rather than to root node, like you're doing)? Btw, typically a tree like this would be recursively built, because directories can have both files and sub-directories.

Comment: I can't get something like DirectoryInfo, to get the full path for all nodes. That's why I can't populate Treeview, only directories and files separately.

Comment: Is `fileLink` path to the root directory? If so, can you call `GetNodesFromLink` per directory?

Comment: Yes it is... that's the way I get all files and directories from Mega link... then I'm just using a filter to get both separately. I'm using this line to get all directories: 

var directories = nodes.Where(x => x.Type == NodeType.Directory);

Comment: The way you're doing it isn't typically done, nor is there a good solution to that method. The call to `GetNodesFromLink` needs to happen *per directory* in a loop, in a recursive function. You have all the necessary info to do that from the first call. Basically, you have a directory tree with 2 object types, and you need to write a DFS traversal of that tree.

Comment: Ok, I got the idea. Let me try something else and I'll let u know. Thank you.